# Spacy : Named entity Recognition on dates not working as expected

Tags: python, date, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am not sure that I understand exactly how spacy identifies named entites in a text, and in my case especially dates.

I am trying to extract the education + the respective date in a text document. I have something like this

```
text = 'University of A  2019 - 2020
        University of B  2016 - 2019
        College A        2013 - 2016
        College B        2008 - 2013'
doc = nlp(text)
for ent in doc.ents:
     print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

Which gives me as output :

```
University of A  ORG
University of B  ORG
2016 - 2019      DATE
2013 - 2016      DATE
2008 - 2013      DATE
```

As expected the universities are recognized as organizations and I expected spacy not to recognize the colleges as it's less obvious than the university names. However I do not understand why I lost the first date but all the others work fine.

I tried on another text that was something like this :

```
1997 : any text
1998 : any text
1999 : any text
...
2018 : any text
```

And here all dates where recognized except 2013 and 2018, although the format of the lines are the same as all the others.

Is there a way to train spacy to better recognize the dates or should I use another tool? I'm already using spacy for other parts of the same program. I'm not using regex right now cause the dates can be in so many different formats (only year, beginning year - end year, sometimes months and days too, etc.)

Comment: What model are you using? I have `[('2019 - 2020', 'DATE'), ('2016 - 2019', 'DATE'), ('2013 - 2016', 'DATE'), ('2008 - 2013', 'DATE')]` as output with `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')`

Comment: I'm using "en_core_web_sm" or "fr_core_news_sm" conditionally based on the language of the text, as it can be french or english. I'm using spacy 2.3.4 maybe that's why?

Comment: Yes, and I am not sure there is a `fr_core_news_sm` model for spacy 3.0.1. Try with a more feature-rich model like `..._lg`. `spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')`, for example.

Comment: There seems to be a spacy.load('fr_dep_news_trf' for french) for spacy 3.0.1 so I might upgrade and then check if it works better

Comment: Yes, please check as it may solve the problem.

Comment: It seems to be working however I get an error when installing 'fr_dep_news_trf' with the command given by the spacy website, so guess that will be my next issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a more feature-rich model type, the one with `_md` or `_lg` suffix with spacy 2.x and `_trf` with spacy 3.x.

For example, you may install

```py
python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf
```

Then, you may use

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')
text = '''University of A  2019 - 2020
         University of B  2016 - 2019
         College A        2013 - 2016
         College B        2008 - 2013'''
doc = nlp(text)
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

Output:

```
2019 - 2020 DATE
2016 - 2019 DATE
2013 - 2016 DATE
2008 - 2013 DATE
```